# Wallpaper change event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wallpaper

Can I get a wallpaper changed event in a broadcast receiver?
I need to detect if the user changed the wall paper.
How could I do it?

What I am doing is this:
I have an app that changes wallpaper automaticly.
If the user changes it manually using a different aplication I would like to notice it and ask the users if he/she wants to add that new wallpaper to the list in my application

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  It helps people answer questions if you provide information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok. what I am doing is this:
I have an app that changes wallpaper automaticly everyday.
If the user changes it manually using a different aplication I would like to notice it and ask the users if he/she wants to add that new wallpaper to the list in my application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only a broadcast for when a wallpaper image changes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED

To do what you want, you will need to have more logic to use this to determine if the wallpaper has been changed to something besides an image: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo()

To be honest, if you are making a wallpaper that is going to change, you really should consider just writing a live wallpaper.  This will fit much more comfortably into the system: you can change what you are showing whenever you want, and it is clear when the user has selected a different wallpaper because your live wallpaper will be stopped.

Also you need to be extremely careful about the use of ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED, because it can get you into bad interactions with other applications.  Here is the documentation for it that will appear in the next API:

```
/**
 * Broadcast Action:  The current system wallpaper has changed.  See
 * {@link android.app.WallpaperManager} for retrieving the new wallpaper.
 * This should <em>only</em> be used to determine when the wallpaper
 * has changed to show the new wallpaper to the user.  You should certainly
 * never, in response to this, change the wallpaper or other attributes of
 * it such as the suggested size.  That would be crazy, right?  You'd cause
 * all kinds of loops, especially if other apps are doing similar things,
 * right?  Of course.  So please don't do this.
 *
 * @deprecated Modern applications should use
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER
 * WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER} to have the wallpaper
 * shown behind their UI, rather than watching for this broadcast and
 * rendering the wallpaper on their own.
 */
```

True story.

Comment: +1 for the info the new API has it deprecated. Now there's no way to find if the wallpaper has changed ?

Comment: `Modern applications should use #FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER` -- That's all fine, unless you want to blur the wallpaper behind your app, since Android apparently has no way to do that (that I've found out about).

Comment: @RobinJ that is exactly what I am trying to do to! Going crazy here to get this working...

Comment: @Boy https://github.com/RobinJ1995/be.robinj.ubuntu/blob/master/UbuntuLauncher/app/src/main/java/be/robinj/ubuntu/unity/Wallpaper.java :) In recent versions of Android there seems to be no way of receiving a signal when the wallpaper was changed, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that anything gets broadcast.

[WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) does have some getters that will return the current wallpaper to you as a drawable. Perhaps you could compare the current one to a stored copy to determine if it has been changed. However if you are using this functionality to trick users by changing the wallpaper after they already set it, do know, I hope you step on a lego in the dark with your bare foot.

Comment: I don't think comparing is a good solution. How often should I compare? every minute? every hour? (battery is like gold).
 
 What I am doing is this:
I have an app that changes wallpaper automaticly.
If the user changes it manually using a different aplication I would like to notice it and ask the users if he/she wants to add that new wallpaper to the list in my application

Comment: I think it is the only solution that is available to you. But also if battery is like gold then people wouldn't be using an auto wallpaper switcher...