# Stop user to not to change the wallpaper already set in android programmatically

Tags: android

In my application I have set a wallpaper and want to stop user to change this wallpaper for some time, mean disable setting wallpaper feature of android for some time. Can anybody tell me how can i do ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592091/wallpaper-change-event

Answer (score 3):

There is no such way to patronize the user on their own device. Moreover, imagine what user experience that would be.

There might be a workaround, but I highly discourage you to use any.